# Write to a file in local storage flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages

I know about the `path_provider` package but it doesn't do what i want, or maybe I'm not just using it right. I read after so many trials and errors that the `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` returns a directory that is accessible only by the app itself, but what if i want to write to a phone's local document directory or so and be able to view the file in my file explorer later on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save where the file explorer reaches, you must use the method `getExternalStorageDirectory()`. It only works in Android and you'll need `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions.

Actually, you're able to find the files saved using `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` and `getTemporaryDirectory()` as well, but you'd need root access.